# Accessing users Yahoo profile with YQL

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo, yql

I am trying to access users Yahoo profile using YQL. For this, I am using OAuth with YQL. The query I'm using to get this data is:

`q=select%20*%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%20%3D%20me&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=`

However, when I do this, I am getting the following error message:
`Unsupported authorization scheme: "Bearer"`

Are there any other things that I need to set before making the request, like headers or any other fields?

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo YQL endpoint does not support OAuth 2.0 tokens (yet?). You can use a REST API as described in https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/social_dir_api.html#social_dir_intro-profiles, e.g. https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/extended-profile-resource.html:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/profile?format=json
```